# Running Launch4J from java code?

Tags: java, runtime, launch4j

I have used launch4j to wrap an executable jar into an exe in my pom.xml (maven project file) file during compile/build time.

But is it possible to run launch4J from a piece of java code and creating an exe wrapper dynamically when the java application is executed, like:

```
import some.l4j.dependencies.*;
public class L4JTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Launch4JConfig l4jConfig = new Launch4JConfig ();
       l4jConfig.setJarPath("path-to-jar-to-wrap");
       l4jConfig.setOutfile("test.exe")
       l4jConfig.setDontWrapJar(true);
        ...
       l4jConfig.create();
  }
}
```

Any pointers or links to examples are welcome!

Comment: Did you consider using command line for launch4J and then calling it from a java program using ` Runtime.getRuntime().exec(....);`

Comment: Yeah that would be the "bruteforce" way, but maybe there is a java friendly API that could be included/used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not want to go thorough the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` way, you will have to tinker around. We have used launch4J and we never had the use-case that you are looking for. I do not think launch4J has a documented Java API.

However, you may tinker with the Ant task used in launch4J and use it for your purpose here.
Have a look at the [task's source](http://massapi.com/source/launch4j-3.0.2-linux/launch4j/src/net/sf/launch4j/ant/Launch4jTask.java.html)

You will see that it makes use of `net.sf.launch4j.Builder` and `net.sf.launch4j.config.Config` to "build" the EXE.

- good luck!